# Magento Bootstrap Menu expands on reload then collapses

Tags: frontend, menu, navigation

I have a bootstrap nav in my store. When the page loads the whole expanded menu shows then flashes to normal. Im not sure what Im missing.

```
<?php if ($_menu): ?>
        <nav id="headerNav" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-main" role="navigation">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-main-collapse">
                    <span class="sr-only"><?php echo $this->__('Toggle Navigation') ?></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="container">
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-main-collapse">
                <ul id="headerNavigation" class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <?php echo $_menu ?>
                    <li class="brandsTop"><a href="/brands" ><span>Brands</span></a></li>
                    <li class="scratchTop"><a href="/scratch-and-dent" ><span>Scratch &amp; Dent</span></a></li>
                    <li class="promotionsTop"><a href="/promotions-and-rebates" ><span>Promotions &amp; Rebates</span></a></li>
                    <li class="partsTop last"><a href="/parts-department" ><span>Parts Department</span></a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            </div>
        </nav>

<?php endif ?>
```